# How do I open a text file named today's date?

Tags: vb.net

Every day I have a script that logs some files through batch, they get todays date as name (ddmmyyyy.txt). So example 07.12.2015.txt. They will be in this folder "C:\copyflow\Log\filehistory\"

Now I have want a button in my program that opens the file of today.

I obviously can't do this; process.start("C:\copyflow\Log\filehistory\07.12.2015.txt") because there will be another name each day. So this is what I've come up with, but I seem to be missing something.

```
Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
Dim Historylocation As String = "C:\copyflow\Log\filehistory\"
Process.Start(todaysdate, historylocation)
```

I know this won't work, but I'm not sure how its supposed to be.

Comment: You presumably need to pass the .txt file to the thing that will process it as a command line.

Comment: My thought exactly. Steve (see answer) figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) method that uses two arguments, the first argument is the full path name of the file, while the second one are the arguments passed on the command line and thus is not needed in your context.

So your code should be (after adding the extension to the file to open)

```
Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now)
Dim HistoryFile = Path.Combine("C:\copyflow\Log\filehistory", todaysdate)
Process.Start(HistoryFile)
```

I would also add a check with `File.Exists(HistoryFile)` to give an appropriate error message in case of problems

Comment: YES, you nailed it. Thanks! Side note, I had to change the `path.combine` to `IO.path.combine` for some reason. I wouldn't know, luckily a suggestion from Visual studio came up.

Comment: Your file has no _Imports System.IO_ but it is just a simple way to avoid some keystrokes, Your way is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanting to open the file i do:

```
dim Today as string = system.datetime.now
Process.Start("C:\copyflow\Log\" + Today)
```

you can even get the drive:

```
Dim MainDrive As string = Environ("systemdrive") + "\"
```

Or

```
Dim MainDrive As string = Mid(Enviroment.getfolderpath(Enviroment.specialfolder.system),1,3)
```

Comment: This will load different files in countries with different date formatting schemes (e.g. MM/DD/YYYY vs. DD/MM/YYYY vs. YYYY.DD.MM etc.).

Comment: then just use my.computer.clock to get the date time. get the local time and then substring if needed.